# Add my own bundle sources to pax-exam when building with pax-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, osgi, pax

I'm trying to build my OSGI bundle with [pax-maven-build](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/maven-pax-plugin/) and in the same time test it with [pax-exam](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam). It have some bundle in provision than I can test with the following pax-exam test configuration:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4TestRunner.class)
@ExamReactorStrategy(AllConfinedStagedReactorFactory.class)
public class OSGILoaderTest {

    @Inject
    protected BundleContext bundleContext;

    @Configuration
    public Option[] config() throws MalformedURLException {


        String projectRoot = // a path to my project

        return options(
                junitBundles(),
                equinox(),
                bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.core.variables_3.2.500.v20110511.jar"),
                bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20110423-0524.jar"),
                bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.4.300.v20110228.jar"),
                // etc...
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void getBundleContext() throws RodinDBException {
        IRodinDB rodinDB = RodinCore.getRodinDB();
        assertNotNull(rodinDB);
    }
}
```

Here, I can see I can access to the IRodinDB instance from a jar I have provisonned.

Now I have code my own bundle, which is going to use all the jar provisionned. But I cannot even test my own code, for instance:

```
@Test
public void checkAccessToRodinDbTest() {
    VTGService service = null;
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

give an error **at compilation time**:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.ops4j:maven-pax-plugin:1.5:testCompile (default-testCompile) : Compilation failure
>
> [ERROR] cannot find symbol
>
> [ERROR] symbol  : class VTGService

It seems test compilation cannot see 'src/main/java', contrarly as expected by the default behavior of maven-compiler-plugin. But in my case, you can see than maven does not use the compiler plugin but instead maven-pax-plugin.

The question is: how can i test my own bundle with pax-exam ?

**update1**

It seems that this is a problem with recent version of maven-pax-plugin, as [the basic example available in ops4j pax maven plugin](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/maven-pax-plugin/usage.html) (in section *Using the Pax Plugin inside a POM*) seems to suffer of the same problem.

**update2**

As requested by Dmytro, this is the pom.xml of my bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <relativePath>../poms/compiled/</relativePath>
        <groupId>fr.xlim.ssd.vtg.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>compiled-bundle-settings</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <bundle.symbolicName>fr.xlim.ssd.vtg.bundle</bundle.symbolicName>
        <bundle.namespace>fr.xlim.ssd.vtg.bundle</bundle.namespace>
    </properties>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.xlim.ssd.vtg</groupId>
    <artifactId>fr.xlim.ssd.vtg.bundle</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${bundle.symbolicName}</name>

    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <type>pom</type>
            <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>provision</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- not needed as equinox bundle are available in provision --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi_R4_core</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi_R4_compendium</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.url</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-url-mvn</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-container-native</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-link-mvn</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

I am not sure it is the most elegant solution, but I created a new maven project when I can import my own bundle like in the source code of my question.

Is there an elegant way to add my own java sources directly as new bundle for test in the same Maven project ? It could be not possible (as the bundle assembly operation is done **after** the compilation and tests)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following setup to provision the bundle under test. When configuring the test, I provision the bundle using the `reference`-protocol (this is a non-standard feature of Equinox and Felix, see [here](http://team.ops4j.org/browse/PAXURL-137)):

```
@Configuration
public Option[] config() {

    return options(         
        bundle("reference:file:target/classes"),
        junitBundles(),
        felix()
        );
}
```

The test-cases also run when you specify `knopplerfish()` as the environment. I guess that is because the URL is resolved by Pax Exam, and not by the OSGi-runtime. I use the [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) to build my bundles. To make this work as expected, you have to add the following configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <!-- This execution makes sure that the manifest is available 
                    when the tests are executed -->
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Otherwise the manifest will not be available when the tests are run, since by default it is generated during the `package`-phase.

I hope I did not forget anything - please let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: Thanks, juste one question: are you testing with pax-exam in the same maven project than your bundle ?

Comment: Yes, that is the point of this configuration. The tests are executed during maven `test`-phase.

Comment: Seems to work, need some tests but you are the best solution so far ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Check [PaxExam docs](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam+Maven+Dependencies) how to configure your Maven POM with PaxExam.

Samples [here](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2/tree/master/itest/src/it/regression-multi)

Comment: OK but for building and provisioning maven-pax-plugin offers a lot. If I need to dump it (as not supported by pax-exam), what is the replacement ?

Comment: sorry, maven-pax-plugin is a part of Pax Construct. You can use plain PaxExam for unit tests. You can use different goals from maven-pax-plugin (e.g. pax:provision etc.)

Comment: If i understand clearly, you advice me to switch from maven-pax-plugin to pax-construct ?

Comment: maven-pax-plugin is a part of pax-construct project. Could you provide your pom.xml to see how you use maven-pax-plugin, pls?

Comment: Thanks for you update. looks like maven-pax-plugin is described in the parent pom.